# ValueAnimator doesn't return fractions and values

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to use value animator to get values that it animates between.
I want to control animation on my own (go back and forth as I wish) in canvas.
But for some reason it won't set these values.

```
ValueAnimator _vaX = ValueAnimator.ofInt(_current.point.x, _next.point.x);
_vaX.setDuration(500);
CL.v(_vaX.getAnimatedFraction() + " and " +_vaX.getValues().length);
```

Output for this is always "0.0 and  1", no matter what I use for input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not starting the animation, which means the `getAnimatedFraction()` will always return `0.0`. `getValues()` returns `PropertyValuesHolder[]`, maybe this is the reason why the length is only `1`

Comment: I tried to get it right after starting. Same result. Perhaps I should try it on animation listener, maybe it "really" starts only there.

Comment: Yeah, is there any reason why not to use the AnimationUpdateListener to access the current progress values of the animation?

Comment: Yes, I just want to get all the values in array or any form so I can iterate them on my own. I created my own function to do it for linear transitions, but now if I want some other easing types.